# Subtract values from running total using DAX

Tags: powerbi

I have the following table:

```
Date        Measure1    Measure2    Output
11-02-2019  8           0.4         8
12-02-2019  8           0.4         7.6
13-02-2019  8           0.4         7.2
14-02-2019  8           0.4         6.8
15-02-2019  8           0.4         6.4
16-02-2019  8           0.4         6
17-02-2019  8           0.4         5.6
```

I want to subtract the value from previous row in power bi. How to update the value of measure in or value of variable.

- Measure1 - Holds one value which will change if some filter is changed.
- Measure 2 - Holds the value and depend upon filter for change.
- Measure 3 (Output) - This is based on calculation,Want to subtract the value from previous row.

measure1 = measure1 - measure2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the kind of dax that will let you do something that looks like a running total.  I leave it to you to straighten up the column and table names.

```
RunningTotal = 
CALCULATE(
   FIRSTNONBLANK(Table1[StartingVal], TRUE()) - SUM(Table1[Change])
   , FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table1)
      , [DayOfMonth] <= MAX(Table1[DayOfMonth])
   )
)
```

This takes advantage of the filter portion of the 'CALCULATE' function to sum values in the field [Change] that are on rows whose value in [DayOfMonth] are less than or equal to the value of [DayOfMonth].  The resulting sum is subtracted from the first value in the column [StartingVal] that is part of our context.  In the strictest sense, this is not a running total.  The measure has no 'look back' capabilty to find a value in a previous row because the very concept of row is quite unreliable in DAX.  There are only subtables and filtered contexts.

[image]

Comment: If StartingVal and change is measure value, not a column and DayOf Month is a Calendar table. Please suggest how do I manage in this case.

Comment: Ok, so you have two aggregate measures, and a date table, and no relationship.  Maybe you can hack something out to count the rows of DATESBETWEEN for min date and max date of ALLSELECTED([Dates]), multiply that count by Change and subtract it from StartingVal?  I dunno.  Feels like a reach.